# Django ListView pagination using get_queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have been trying to learn and get to grips with ListViews with pagination in Django, but I seem to be having some trouble in understanding concepts. So, let me show some code - my view.py looks something like this:

```
class SearchDisplayListView(ListView):
    model = BlogPosts
    template_name = "searchres_list.html"
    paginate_by = '15'
    context_object_name = "searchres"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchDisplayListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        q = self.request.GET.get('q')
        q = q.replace(" ","+")
        context['searchq'] = q
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(SearchDisplayListView, self).get_queryset()
        # Get the q GET parameter
        q = self.request.GET.get('q')
        q = q.replace(" ","+")
        if q is None:
        # Return the base queryset
        return queryset
        # Return a filtered queryset
       ## do some awesome calculations using "q" i.e send request to search server
       ## get back a list from the search server.. example: range(0,100)
        queryset = range(0,100)
        return queryset
```

As you can see, I do not actually populate my queryset using Models - but rather from my own "search server" which returns me results - say in this example range(0,100).

Now, I am trying to use the following in my template code:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<tbody>
{% for i in searchres %}
<tr>
<td><img src="http://placehold.it/140x140" class="img-polaroid"></td>
<td>{{i}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

and my pagination looks as follows:

```
{% if is_paginated %}
<div class="pagination pagination-centered">
    <ul>
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
<li><a href="/search/?q={{searchq}}/page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Prev</a></li>
        {% endif %}

        {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
<li><a href="/search/?q={{searchq}}/page={{ page_obj.number }}">{{i}}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
<li><a href="/search/?q={{searchq}}/page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
        {% endif %}

    </ul>
</div>
```

Now, I have the following problems:

[1] Although the template seems to paginate the first set (i.e 0 to 14), I am not able to see the other values in the subsequent pages. So, when I click on next page, I get:

```
 - http://mydata:8000/search/?q=myquery/page=2
```

and when I click next page again, I get:

```
 - http://mydata:8000/search/?q=boots/page=2/page=2
```

which is obviously wrong. I am not able to see how I can generate:

```
 - http://mydata:8000/search/?q=boots/page=3
```

[2] Even when I manually set:

```
 - http://mydata:8000/search/?q=boots/page=3
```

I see values again from 0 to 14 rather than the logical set in page:3.

Also, this basically tells me that on each page, the get_queryset seems to run, generating the first 0 to 14 values - which is not what I want.

As you can see, I have my own custom data set in get_queryset - rather than any DB interaction - so, I am unsure how I can paginate this custom data.

Thanks for your time reading my rather long post!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Query parameters must be separated by **& not /**

```
/search/?q={{searchq}}/page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}
```

should be:

```
/search/?q={{searchq}}&page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}
```

Also, it is best practice to use URL resolver instead of hard-coding the url, something like:

```
{% url 'search' searchq page_obj.previous_page_number %}
```

Comment: That is simply awesome. I just spent a day to figure this out! Do you know where this is mentioned in the docs? Thanks again - accepted your answer.

Comment: just another quick question - if I use the url resolver as you have suggested - how do I set up my urls.py corresponding to it? i.e how do I pass searchq, page_obj.previous_page_number to my urls.py?

Comment: @JohnJ regarding the query params, this is how HTTP works and it has nothing to do with django. for URL resolver, actually it will not work with query parameters, but at least for the first part you can use it. {% url 'myaapp.views.search' %}?q={{searchq}}&page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }} will just work. u dont have to do anything in urls.py in this case. more details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-url

Comment: thanks for that - I understand what you mean - I guess my brain got fried up looking for & !

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, the code should be:

```
{% if is_paginated %}
    <div class="pagination pagination-centered">
    <ul>
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <li><a href="/search/?q={{searchq}}&page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number}}">Prev</a></li>
    {% endif %}

    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
       {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
          <li><a href="/search/?q={{searchq}}&page={{ i }}">{{i}}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
          <li><a href="/search/?q={{searchq}}&page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
    {% endif %}

</ul>
</div>
```

There are two changes: 1. page_obj.number returns the actual page so it is replaced by the incremeting variable i.
2. The for loop is moved inside of the page_obj.has_next for clarity. If you do it this way the pagenumber links are only shown if there is more than this page like the questioner intended it. If you want to show it anyway: just move it out.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a complex, but generic reusable solution, after researching this problem for a while and starting from this entry.

Overkill for the OP, but lots of folks seem to have pagination and search issues, so here's my $.02.

**(Bit of a newbie to Django, so I am sure there are things to be improved, but I am able to combine search and pagination really quickly now.  And please disregard anything about 'db' or 'mdb', this is highly specific to my app which frequently does raw SQL outside of the Django database.)**

**Synopsis:**

Basically, I figured that I could kill two birds with one stone.  The reason I was working on a filtered rowset is because I was driving a search from a Form.

And... the form is quite capable of providing the information required to rebuild the pagination URLs.

So, basically ended up with a system where the work mostly consists of building up a normal Search Form, then wiring it up with an appropriately subclassed version of a ListView.  see  class RoleListView.

I also need to create the listview's template, but if you refer to it, @ pssecurity/security_list.html you'll see it is pretty basic.

**Details:**

The smarts about the pagination is on class KSearchListView(ListView). This stuff is entirely generic, I can reuse it on as many search pages as I want.

methods get_queryset, where the database filtering is taking place by calling the form.doSearch.

the actual pagination is on method get_context_data, which checks if there is a form, if it is valid and then manipulates the pagination URLs by repopulating it with the form's cleaned parameters.

Note also that there are two incoming URLs, one unfiltered, the list, and one filtered, the search).  Both map to the same ListView.

```
urls

    #Roles aka PSROLEDEFN
    url(r'^roles/search',
        login_required(RoleListView.as_view()),
        name="psroledefn_search"),

    url(r'^roles/$',
        # 'pssecurity.views.psroledefn_list',
        login_required(RoleListView.as_view()),
        name="psroledefn_list"),



        #generic
class KSearchListView(ListView):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__

    __repr__ = __str__

    form_class = form = None
    di_hardcoded_context = {}

    def setdb(self):
        #specific to my app
        self.db = self.rdb

    def dispatch(self,*args,**kwargs):
        #specific to my app
        if not self.mdb:
            self.mdb = MultiDb.get(self.kwargs["dbr"])
            self.djangodb = self.mdb.djangodb
            self.rdb = self.mdb.rdb
            self.setdb()
        #specific to my app

        return super(KSearchListView, self).dispatch(*args,**kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self,*args,**kwargs):
        # logging.info("%s.get_queryset(%s,%s)" % (self,args,kwargs))

        self.request.get = self.request.GET

        if self.form_class:
            #pagination info
            #do we have a form and are we coming from it?
            if self.request.method == "GET":
                self.form = self.form_class(self.db, self.request.GET)

                if self.form.is_valid():
                    logging.info("form.doSearch")
                    li_c = self.form.doSearch()
                    return li_c
                else:
                    logging.debug("not is_valid branch")
            else:
                self.form = self.form_class(self.mdb.rdb)
        #fetch all rows for the underlying table
        return self.fetch_all()

    def fetch_all(self):
        #specific to my app
        #you would probably use a <model>.objects.all()
        return list(pssys.Pssys.fetch(self.db,self.recname))


    def _override_context_data(self,context):
        pass

    def get_context_data(self,*args,**kwargs):
        # logging.info("%s.get_context_data(%s,%s)" % (self,args,kwargs))

        context = super(KSearchListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.form
        context["dbr"] = self.mdb.rdbname


        #pagination info
        #we are going to put the GET variables right back into the next/prev
        url = ""
        page_obj = context["page_obj"]
        if self.form and self.form.is_valid() and self.form.cleaned_data:

            li = [self.request.path,"?"]

            #driving the url assembly from the form fields and
            #using the cleaned data should be pretty safe
            di = self.form.cleaned_data
            for k in self.form.fields:
                li.append("%s=%s" % (k,di[k]))
                li.append("&")
            # li = li[:-1]
            url = "".join(li)

        #if we didn't come in through a search form
        if not url:
            url = "?"

        #now conditionally add the previous/next as appropriate. 
        #url has either a trailing ? or & at this point
        kpaging_previous_url = kpaging_next_url = ""
        if page_obj.has_previous():
            kpaging_previous_url = context["kpaging_previous_url"] = url + "page=%s" % (page_obj.previous_page_number())
        if page_obj.has_next():
            kpaging_next_url = context["kpaging_next_url"] = url + "page=%s" % (page_obj.next_page_number())

        logging.debug("url:%s" % (url))
        logging.debug("kpaging_previous_url:%s" % (kpaging_previous_url))
        logging.debug("kpaging_next_url:%s" % (kpaging_next_url))

        #pickup anything the subclass has set for the context
        context.update(self.di_hardcoded_context)
        self._override_context_data(context)
        return context


        #what I need to write for every list/search page...

class RoleListView(KSearchListView):

    template_name = "pssecurity/security_list.html" 
    paginate_by = 20
    recname = "PSROLEDEFN"
    form_class = Search_PSROLEDEFN
    di_hardcoded_context = dict(
        title="Search Roles",
        header="Roles",
        templatename_inst="PSROLEDEFN_list",
        url_action='security:psroledefn_search')

#pagination info the forms

        #generic
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, db, request=None):
        self.db = db
        li_arg = [request] if request else []

        super(forms.Form, self).__init__(*li_arg)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__

    __repr__ = __str__


        #what I need to write for every list/search page...
class Search_PSROLEDEFN(SearchForm):
    ROLENAME = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False)
    DESCR = forms.CharField(max_length=32, required=False)

    status_custom = ChooseStatusCustomizationField()
    hasUsers = ChooseYesNoDontCareField("has Users?")
    hasPermissions = ChooseYesNoDontCareField("has Permissions?")
    hasPortalReferences = ChooseYesNoDontCareField("has Portal?")

    def doSearch(self):

        ROLENAME = self.cleaned_data["ROLENAME"]
        DESCR = self.cleaned_data["DESCR"].strip()
        status_custom = self.cleaned_data["status_custom"]

        hasPortalReferences = self.cleaned_data["hasPortalReferences"]
        hasPermissions = self.cleaned_data["hasPermissions"]
        hasUsers = self.cleaned_data["hasUsers"]

        #cut out a lot of code specific to my app
        #you would want to do an appropriate
        #<model>.objects.filter()...
        returns <select from my db>




#a typical template, note that isn't even specific to an object
#refer to class RoleListView to see how the template is built.
#the actual details of the fetched objects are left to <templatename_inst>

pssecurity/security_list.html
{% block search %}
<div id="block_search">
<span>{{header}}</span>

<div class="row">
{% if form %}

<div id="search" class="well col-xs-9" >
    <form class= "form-horizontal" action="{% url url_action dbr=dbr %}" method="get">
        {{form.as_table}}
        <input type="submit" value="search">
    </form>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{%block content %}
<div id = "block_content">
{% for inst in object_list %}
    <div class="row">
        {% include templatename_inst %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}

{% include "websec/kpagination.html" %}

</div>
{%endblock %}

        #generic
kpagination.html
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links" >
        {% if li_inst.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ li_inst.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current" >
            Page {{ li_inst.number }} of {{ li_inst.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if li_inst.has_next %}
            <a \href="?page={{ li_inst.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do like below in django classbased Listview

views.py

```
try:
    from urllib import urlencode
except ImportError:
    from urllib.parse import urlencode

class MyListView(ListView):
    # ............
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(
            GroupSubsListView, self
        ).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        query_params = self.request.GET.copy()
        query_params.pop('page', None)
        context['query_params'] = urlencode(query_params)
        return context
```

template.html

```
<!-- pagination -->
{% if is_paginated %}
  <p>showing {{ page_obj.start_index }} to {{ page_obj.end_index }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.count }}</p>
  <div class="text-center">
    <nav>
      <ul class="pagination">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}&{{ query_params }}" aria-label="Previous">
            Previous
          </a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link"> Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}. </a></li>
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}&{{ query_params }}" aria-label="Next">
            Next
          </a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
{% endif %}
  <!-- end/ -->
```